# Will webpack adopt an AST as a module input?

Tags: webpack

At the moment webpack deals with files, which it parses via loaders to determine dependencies.

When using babel, babel parses a file and has enough information to tell webpack directly what dependencies it has. As far as I know there's no way to pass this rich information directly to webpack, babel has to generate a JavaScript file as text, which webpack will then re-parse to extract the dependency information.

(a) Is my summary correct? Is this what currently happens?
(b) Are there any plans to allow a tighter integration between layers like this? I would expect this to have a pretty decent impact on build times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) Yes, this summary is correct. That's mostly because there used to be no common AST format across different tools. This has recently changed with the [ESTree Spec](https://github.com/estree/estree). However, I don't know how interoperable these ASTs are in real-world projects. Comparing the AST on [astexplorer.net](http://astexplorer.net/), it looks like the ASTs are somewhat similar. Webpack's current design is wasteful, but it provides good interoperability.

(b) I'm not aware of any plans about this. But I've already thought about it as well. JS is not the only language that is parsed several times: In most webpack build chains, Sass is parsed and transformed to CSS, CSS is parsed by the postcss-loader which usually applies auto-prefixing and outputs CSS, then CSS is parsed again by the css-loader (funnily again by PostCSS) and is transformed to JS which is parsed again by webpack to figure out the dependency graph. This is very inefficient (and [can already be a problem](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/124#issuecomment-202369712)), but this way you're able to integrate any tool that is able to understand the source code.

However, there is a tendency to make compilers more pluggable. Most prominent examples are [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/). And as a consequence, the [autoprefixer-loader](https://github.com/passy/autoprefixer-loader) has been deprecated in favor of a PostCSS plugin. Even official committee members work on APIs to intercept language processing inside the browser like the [CSS-TAG Houdini Task Force](https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts) or the [JavaScript decorators proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators).

I expect more tools like Babel and PostCSS to come. And this will probably lead to less work being done by separate loaders within the webpack build chain and more within these tool environments – which is actually a good thing, because these tools are re-usable outside the webpack context. It would be really good to see more compilers providing means to skip code generation and re-use the AST right away.

Concerning the current situation in webpack:

<strike>There's also a little known loader feature, called [`value`/`inputValue`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#value). It is intended as a way to pass meta information from one loader to another. Thus it can be used as [a shortcut to skip needless parsing](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader/issues/3). You can use this feature with webpack@1. However, this feature is currently not available on the beta branch of webpack@2 (don't know why).</strike>
*— sokra told me that he has removed this legacy feature in webpack@2, so this is not safe to use anymore*

Loaders may have multiple inputs and outputs. Since JavaScript doesn't allow multiple `return` values, outputs can only be achieved by calling `this.callback`. The current convention is that the first value is always the actual loader content. The second value is the source map (if activated). So we could use the third value as a way to pass the AST around. This, however, is currently nowhere implemented. But we could start with it.

---

Btw: [Mark Finger](https://github.com/markfinger) recently did some valuable research on this topic. You may be interested in [his findings](https://github.com/markfinger/unfort) as well.

Comment: The Mark Finger repo (i.e. his research conclusions) is worth reading - much appreciated